# How to access individual items in serialized array?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter, bitconverter

I want to store an array of timestamps in a binary flat file. **One of my requirements is that I can access individual timestamps later on for efficient query purposes without having to read and deserialize the entire array first** (I use a binary search algorithm that finds the file position of a start timestamp and end timestamp which in turn determines which bytes are read and deserialized between those two timestamps because the entire binary file can be multiple gigabytes large in size).

Obviously, the simple but slow way is to use `BitConverter.GetBytes(timestamp)` to convert each timestamp to bytes and to then store them in the file. I can then access each item individually in the file and use my custom binary search algorithm to find the timestamp that matches with the desired timestamp.

However, I found that BinaryFormatter is incredibly efficient (multiple times faster than protobuf-net and any other serializer I tried) regarding serialization/deserialization of value type arrays. Hence I attempted to try to serialize an array of timestamps into binary form. However, apparently that will now prevent me from accessing individual timestamps in the file without having to first deserialize the entire array.

Is there a way to still access individual items in binary form after having serialized an entire array of items via BinaryFormatter?

Here is some code snippet that demonstrates what I mean:

```
var sampleArray = new int[5] { 1,2,3,4,5};

        var serializedSingleValueArray = sampleArray.SelectMany(x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x)).ToArray();
        var serializedArrayofSingleValues = Serializers.BinarySerializeToArray(sampleArray);

        var deserializesToCorrectValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(serializedSingleValueArray, 0); //value = 1 (ok)
        var wrongDeserialization = BitConverter.ToInt32(serializedArrayofSingleValues, 0); //value = 256 (???)
```

Here the serialization function:

```
public static byte[]BinarySerializeToArray(object toSerialize)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Formatter.Serialize(stream, toSerialize);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Edit: I do not need to concern myself with efficient memory consumption or file sizes as those are currently by far not the bottlenecks. It is the speed of serialization and deserialization that is the bottleneck for me with multi-gigabyte large binary files and hence very large arrays of primitives.

Comment: I don't think that is going to be available via `BinaryFormatter`, and frankly: even if it was, I *still* couldn't find it in me to recommend `BinaryFormatter`. What is the data here; is it *just* the timestamps? writing it manually with fixed-size payloads may be your best option in this case; note: there are *much* better options than `BitConverter.GetBytes`

Comment: in particular: see the methods under `BinaryPrimitives` that provide endianness-aware conversions between spans and primitives

Comment: @MarcGravell, long[], double[], and decimal[], with long[] being the timestamps in tick representation. Serialization and deserialization with BinaryFormatter is orders of magnitude faster than any other serializer I have come across (deserialization was over 20 times faster than with the newest version of protobuf-net [raw, unconfigured].

Comment: I may have some interest in looking at your scenario with example sizes if there's a genuine "this should probably be faster" - but I wonder whether switching to fixed-length encoding would help (`DataFormat`). However! protobuf *still* isn't directly engineered for random access of elements (unless you use the raw reader API, etc)

Comment: @MarcGravell, point taken, though I doubt BinaryPrimitives would in sum surpass the deserialization of an entire array of primitives via BinaryFormatter, though I would need to test that.

Comment: @MarcGravell, could you please elaborate on how you think BinaryPrimitives play into this issue? I am not struggling with endianess. And I do not see an overload that handles doubles. Perhaps I misunderstand that BinaryPrimitives was only created to solve a problem the other APIs did not solve, the ability to specify endianess?

Comment: partly endianness; partly to provide support for spans (a lot of stuff is looking towards spans rather than byte[] now - it enables a number of very useful scenarios); re `double`; yeah, it is missing on that API; a common approach there is to reinterpret between `double`/`long`, which can be done using `unsafe`, or via `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` or `BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble`

Comment: Or: if you're dealing with an *array* of doubles; you can use `MemoryMarshal.Cast<,>`, which allows you to reinterpret a span between types - *incredibly* useful - especially for SIMD scenarios (for example, re-interpret a `double[]` as a `Span<Vector<double>>` - instant SIMD chunking, zero allocation) - in your case you'd presumably use `Cast<long, double>` or `Cast<double, long>`

Comment: unfortunatly the reference source for the BinaryFormatter is not public, it's hidden in __BinaryFormatter, most often they do unsafe memory access, when handling arrays. I put an alternative in another answer, if you just want to get around this item by item handling.

Comment: @Marc Gravel, thanks, will read up and try out some approaches with Spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is just "how to convert an array of struct,to byte[]" you have other options than BitConverter. `BitConverte`r is for single values, the `Buffer` class is for arrays.

```
        double[] d = new double[100];
        d[4] = 1235;
        d[8] = 5678;
        byte[] b = new byte[800];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(d, 0, b, 0, d.Length*sizeof(double));

        // just to test it works
        double[] d1 = new double[100];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, d1, 0, d.Length * sizeof(double));
```

This does a byte-level copy without converting anything and without iterating over items.

You can put this byte array directly to your stream (not a StreamWriter, not a Formatter)

```
        stream.Write(b, 0, 800);
```

That's definitly the fastest way to write to a file,but it involves a complete copy, but probably also any other thinkable method, will read an item, store it first for some reason, before it goes to the file.

If this is the only thing you write to your file - you don't need to write the array-length in the file, you can use the file-length for this.

To read the 100th double value in the file:

```
    file.Seek(100*sizeof(double), SeekOrigin.Begin);
    byte[] tmp = new byte[8];
    f.Read(tmp, 0, 8);
    double value = BitConverter.ToDouble(tmp, 0);
```

Here, for single value, you can use `BitConverter`.

This is the solution for .NET Framework, C# <= 7.0

For .NET Standard/.NET Core, C# 8.0 you have more options with `Span<T>`, which gives you access to the internal memory, without copying the Data.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that. Guess it's time to read up on Spans.

Comment: I mark this answer as accepted because you addressed the question on raw performance of transforming large arrays of longs to bytes and back.

Answer (score 0):

A Bitconverter is not a "slow" version, it's just a way to convert everything to a byte[] sequence. This is actually not costly, it's just interpreting the memory differently.

Computing the position in file, load 8 bytes, convert it to DateTime, you are done.

You should do it only with simple structured files, and with simple structured files you don't need a binary formatter. Just load/save your one array to one file. This way you can be sure your file-positions can be computed.

So in other words. Save your array yourself, Date byte Date, than you can load it also Date by Date.

Writing with one processing style, Reading with another, is always a bad idea.

Comment: That is what I am currently doing, and it works well, but with larger file sizes and hence larger arrays of primitives BinaryFormatter far surpasses element by element serialization, speed-wise, via BitConverter by serializing/deserializing entire arrays of primitives.

Comment: No, there is no array to byte-array converter. Also looked for that. But this is just an in-memory copy of this array, that's relativly fast. But I don't think this is much faster than writing one by one , cause the output stream is cashed by the stream you are writing to,anyway.
Howevern, than your use of BinaryFormatter was a missleading way. This is intended to serialize complex structures, like classes containing classes, containing lists of classes. For a simple array, there is no gain. It does not result in a random-accessible file.

Comment: I am aware it's not a random access file result hence my question. I will run a quick comparison between one by one processing vs array processing via Binaryformatter and post the result back here, I remember that it was a lot faster via Binaryformatter (specifically speaking of arrays of primitives)

Comment: *Is there a way to still access individual items in binary form after having serialized* is a direct request for a random access file. Set the file pointer to a position and read it.

Comment: BinaryFormatter performs on average almost 10 times faster than BitConverter on arrays of value types. That is what motivated my question. A hardcore requirement so far is having a random access file, although I am intrigued by the idea of blobs and just providing a random accessible index to said blobs.